# QGIS - Aggregating in virtual field

Tags: qgis, filter, aggregate

I'm using Qgis 3.10.

I have two layers, let's say A and B. In layer A, there is informations about construction work (one row by construction). Each construction has an ID (ID-A). In layer B, there informations about the roads affected by each constructions (one row by road). Each road is linked to the construction by an ID (ID-B).

I'm trying to get the maximum value from fieldC in layer B in a virtual field FieldA in layer A, sorted by construction work. I'm using this expression :

```
aggregate('LayerB', 'max',
 expression:= "fieldC",
 filter:= attributes( @parent )['ID-A']="ID-B"
 )
```

The problem is that this expression is working only for some construction. 
I've tried using different filters, different aggregate function, I didn't manage to get the correct result. Is there something I did wrong ?

[image]

Comment: QGIS 3.10 on Ubuntu, it works perfectly. Try `expression:= coalesce("fieldC", 0)`.

Comment: It also works on my computer using your expression. Thanks a lot ! Although, why does this works and not my first expression ?

Comment: I think it's because of `NULL` values, some operations with a `NULL` value return `NULL`, for example : `5 + 2 + 1 + NULL = NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

The fast and working solution (found in the comments) is :

```py
aggregate(
  'LayerB',
  'max',
  expression:= coalesce("fieldC", 0),
  filter:= attributes( @parent )['ID-A']="ID-B"
)
```

The original formula works under Ubuntu but it seems that sometimes, `NULL` nullify the entire expression. `coalesce` take the first non null value in its arguments starting from the left. Here, if `"fieldC"` is `NULL`, `coalesce` replace it with 0.